# Scaffolding in MVC 5

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an application in visual studio 2012 with the MVC 5 project template. I have successfully build my model class and dbcontext class but in controller while scaffolding the controller the following error is coming:

[image]

Here is my model and dbcontext class :

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}

public class UserDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> NewUser { get; set; }
}
```

My connectionstrings in webconfig file:

```
<add name="UserDbContext"
  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\User.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Just chiming in here - I've got the exact same error in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1. No idea how to fix it though.

Comment: UPDATE - Fixed it - my connection string was `<add key=...` instead of `<add name=...`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't identified an identity column for your User table. Just add the Key attribute to your ID column.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you please help me?

Comment: After that "key" adding, did you drop and create db?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the key on a field called `ID` or `UserID` Entity Framework is supposed to do this for you.